# Is there a way to open Mail.App from QuickMailer?

Tags: macos, mail.app

Is there any way to open Mail.App from QuickMailer?

My dock auto-hides to get more screen space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually pretty easy, you just double click the icon in the Menubar.

[image: QuickMailer menubar icon]